# How to send email using jsp page as a template using servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

How can servlet use jsp page as a template to send email? Email content should be the jsp template sent by servlet.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think your question should be: How to use JSP/JSTL to manage email template and How to execute the template to get email content. Sending email is another thing.

Comment: i m not worried about sending email..my concern is how can servlet use jsp template?